# SWIG Cmake inconsistent DLL linkage

Tags: python, c++, dll, cmake, swig

I am using CMake to build a c++ project to a DLL on Windows. I then wish to wrap this for python using SWIG, but in doing so I am receiving warnings about 'Inconsistent DLL linkage'. I gather this refers to incorrect usage of dllexport/dllimport and I need to specify a #define for SWIG? How can I do this in CMake?

My C++ library is built like so in CMake:

```
# glob all the sources
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/core/*.cpp")

add_library(galgcore SHARED ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(galgcore ${GDAL_LIBRARY})

GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER( galgcore
             BASE_NAME GeoAlg
             EXPORT_MACRO_NAME GALGCORE_DLL
             EXPORT_FILE_NAME ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/core/core_exp.h
             STATIC_DEFINE GeoAlg_BUILT_AS_STATIC
)
```

(It is using CMAke to generate the export header).

I am using this library to build a test executable which works well:

```
include(FindGTest)
enable_testing()
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# If *nix, pthread must be specified *after* the googletest libs
if(WIN32)
  set (PTHREAD "")
else(WIN32)
  set (PTHREAD pthread)
endif(WIN32)

add_executable(galgtest test/galg_unittest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(galgtest ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES} galgcore galgfunc ${PTHREAD})
add_test(AllTestsInGalg galgtest "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/test/10_12_1.tif")
```

Finally, the section dealing with swig:

```
### SWIG
# This generates the python bindings
find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

find_package(PythonLibs)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})

set(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "-Wall")
set_source_files_properties("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/python/galg.i" PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
set_property(SOURCE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/python/galg.i" PROPERTY SWIG_FLAGS "-builtin")
SWIG_ADD_MODULE(galg python "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/python/galg.i" ${SOURCES})
SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(galg ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} galgcore)
```

Comment: Where is `SOURCES` defined? Can you elaborate on which functions give you wrong linkage, e.g. round

Comment: @JensMunk The only problems I get are in the SWIG functions (SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES). If I comment that out it works fine (although, ofc, no swig module is produced). You can see `SOURCES` in the first line of the first code block I pasted

Comment: Could it be that your python libraries are 32-bit and your are building a 64-bit DLL? What happens if you let your galgcore library be static?

Comment: nah, I only have 64 bit python. `Inconsistent DLL linkage` is, as far as I know, usually to do with the wrong dllexport/dllimport definition. My problem is this is handled automatically by CMake, so I need to tell CMake/Swig somehow to use the correct define...

Comment: I have done this thousands of times, but I usually do `IGENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER( galgcore)` without specifying explicitly what names to choose etc. This is basically the only difference to my setup here.

Comment: @JensMunk I will give that & static linking a go. So it seems I am not missing any 'magic' swig command or anything?

Comment: No, you are not. I have posted how I do to completely avoid any warnings and have a solution compiling with /W4 or -Wall and treat warning as errors. There is nice trick to have in compiling in debug version without having python installed with debug information. Also, round in defined in differently through `python.h` than through Microsofts `math.h`

Comment: And oh. You have to make sure that all your functions in your public header of your library are properly exported, i.e. you have used the defines generated using `generate_export_header`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full recipe to what I do to completely avoid warnings on Windows:

```
# We don't have Python with debug information installed
if (MSVC)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /wd4127")
  add_definitions(-DSWIG_PYTHON_INTERPRETER_NO_DEBUG)
endif()

find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}) # generated files

if (MSVC)
  set(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "-D_SWIG_WIN32")
endif()

set_source_files_properties(swig_project.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
swig_add_module(swig_project python swig_project.i ${swig_project_HEADERS})

if (MSVC)
  # Potential uninitialized variable in SWIG_AsVal_
  set_source_files_properties( ${swig_generated_file_fullname} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/wd4701")
endif()

if (WIN32)
  # Allow to debug under windows, if debug versions of Python are missing
  string(REPLACE "_d" "" PYTHON_LIBRARIES "${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}")
endif()

swig_link_libraries(swig_project project ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})

if (WIN32)
  # pyconfig.h is not autogenerated on Windows. To avoid warnings, we
  # add a compiler directive
  get_directory_property(DirDefs COMPILE_DEFINITIONS )
  set_target_properties(_swig_project PROPERTIES
  COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "${DirDefs};HAVE_ROUND")
endif()
```

Comment: Thanks. I made a couple of changes in the CMake file and a couple of changes in the interface file and it is now working :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you are using MSVC I think that you will benefit from the hacks above to make debugging work